# Biggest and smallest element of a binary tree haskell

Tags: list, haskell, search, tree

Consider the following definition of trees:

```
Data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Define the function `smallerbigger :: Float -> Tree Float -> ([Float],[Float])` that given a number *n* and a  tree, produces a pair of lists whose elements are smaller and bigger than *n*.

*(the question initially stated that the tree is a search tree, which was done in error).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help and suggestions.

I managed to find a different solution:

```
smallerbigger :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> ([a], [a])
smallerbigger n (Node r e d) = 
    let (e1,e2) = smallerbigger n e
        (d1,d2) = smallerbigger n d
    in if      r>n then (   e1++d1,  r:(e2++d2)) 
       else if r<n then (r:(e1++d1),    e2++d2 )
       else             (   e1++d1,     e2++d2 )
```

Comment: Please tell me what you think or any corrections please!

Comment: your type is incorrect, your code is incorrect, and you shouldn't accept an answer (that deserves a downvote) for which you ask for comments and corrections!

Answer (score 1):

For a list, you could implement a similar algorithm as

```
smallerbigger :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
smallerbigger x xs = go x xs [] []
    where
        go y [] lt gt = (lt, gt)
        go y (z:zs) lt gt
            | z <  y = go y zs (z:lt) gt
            | z >= y = go y zs lt (z:gt)
```

The basic shape of the algorithm will remain the same for a Tree, but the biggest difference will be how you recurse.  You'll need to recurse down both branches, then once you get the result from each branch concatenate them together along with the result from the current node.

If you get stuck implementing this for a tree, feel free to comment and let me know what problem you're experiencing and include a link to your code in a gist/pastebin/whatever.

Comment: +1 for giving a good hint without actually solving the problem

Comment: I think technically nothing in the question specifies that the tree is sorted ("ordered"? what's the correct term?), i.e. the assumption that the left node is smaller than the right node might not always hold.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: "Search tree" usually implies that it's sorted.

Comment: @hammar Sure, I'm just being pedantic. :-) In fact, it would be interesting to device a `Tree` type such that this property (being sorted) is enforced. I suppose in the simplest case you wouldn't use the `Node` constructor but rather a smart constructor which takes care of ordering the arguments as intended?

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. The exercise does not suppose it's a search tree. I editted my question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Here little set of utilities leading to simple solution. Assuming you need lazy function. 
Here your data defition with addition of only show ability for debug

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

Next we need to a little utility for easy tree creating. Following code is building a very unbalanced tree that is very similar to original list.

```
fromList:: [a] -> Tree a
fromList [] = Empty
fromList (x:xs) = Node x Empty (fromList xs)
```

Simple and obvious representation of tree in list form. Order of elements is preserved.

```
asList:: Tree a -> [a]
asList Empty = []
asList (Node x left right) = asList left ++ x: asList right
```

Next we assume we'll need pair of lists that could be lazy regardless of our destination. 
We are keeping ability to work with tree that has infinite structure somewhere in the middle, but not at the last or end element. 
This definition to walk our tree in opposite direction in lazy manner.

```
reverseTree:: Tree a -> Tree a
reverseTree Empty = Empty
reverseTree (Node x left right) = Node x (reverseTree right) (reverseTree left)
```

Next we finally building our procedure. It could create two possible infinite list of elements smaller and bigger than first argument.

```
smallerbigger::Ord a => a-> Tree a -> ([a],[a])
smallerbigger p t = (takeWhile (<p) $ asList t, takeWhile (>p) $ asList $ reverseTree t)

main = let t = fromList [1..10]
    in do
        print t
        print $ smallerbigger 7 t
```

But in other hand we may want to preserve order in second list, while we are sure that we never hit [bottom](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) building first list. So we could drop elements that are equal to target separator and just span out list at it.

```
smallerbigger p = span (<p) . filter(/=p) . asList
```